# SQL Server 2012: Limit the maximum number of rows for count(*) query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to limit the maximum value for count(*), so it stops counting rows after it found N rows?

I tried both **SET ROWCOUNT N** and **TOP N**, but they are ignored when I use SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM (
   SELECT TOP(@MaxRowCount) *
   FROM MyTable
) as q
```

I think your `WITH` solution might not be performant because it has to iterate each row to assign `ROW_NUMBER()`. I believe the solution here will perform better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've checked your query on a table with one millon rows and when I make @MaxRowCount = 1,000,000 your query works about 30% faster. It also automatically chooses the best index, while in my case it would depend on the ORDER BY column.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt you do that with an IF statement after you do a count?

or maybe a subquery?

select count(*) as usercount
from users
where userid in (select top 5000 userid from users)

that would give you a potential usercount of 5000 or less.

Comment: I cannot do it with IF after the query. I want to do this to improve the performance, so the server does not have to load millions of rows.

**where userid in (select top 5000 userid from users)** will not work as well. The IDs in my case have lots of missing values.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself.

```
With OrderedRows AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) AS RowNumber
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT count(*) FROM OrderedRows WHERE RowNumber <= @MaxRowCount;
```